# window.onload doesn't work for wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, styles

It shows all elements now...but I need to display only one of them...

```
`window.onload = function startcal() {
document.getElementById('form1').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('form2').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('form3').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('form4').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('form5').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('form6').style.display = 'none';  
document.getElementById('form7').style.display = 'none';  
}
```

`

Comment: somewhere later in wordpress it is probably overriding your onload. You should be utilizing the library included with wordpress for javascript onload events. I dont know what that is or i could provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you are placing it [wordpress may block js](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript)

You can do this with css alone

```
#form1{display:block;}
#form2,#form3,#form4,#form5,#form6,#form7,#form1{display:none;}
```